# Mpdf - Preview the html before $mpdf->Output();

Tags: php, html, mpdf

I had create a html page which has successfully created and exported as pdf using mpdf functions.

My question is, if it is possible before the

```
$mpdf->Output();
```

to preview the html file as A4 size and edit the output with the

```
contenteditable="true"
```

of each html element (body,tables, p, div, etc).

I had tried, but the view of html output is different than the mpdf output. (different sizes,dimension, images, tables etc)

Comment: Please share more details - what **exactly** do you want to achieve?

Comment: @NicoHaase 4-year-old question, OP hasn't been seen in 3+ years ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the simplest answer (but not necessarily the true answer) is "no."

The reason for my answer is you've asked us to write a book.  Explaining all the Javascript, PHP, and HTML needed to control all the elements to a reasonable (but never infinitely variable) degree without some limitation (which you haven't provided) is a question that can't be answered here.  Consider that HTML is not designed to be printed while PDF is.  PDF can do many things HTML simply cannot.  Only one of the many problems with making a form-creation tool in a web browser is that browsers were literally designed to not care what a piece of paper is and PDF was just as literally designed to care exclusively about what a piece of paper is.

So, the true answer to your question is "yes."  But writing a full tutorial on how to do it is well beyond the scope of this forum.

If you are seeking to learn how to do this, then you need to understand both the pros and the cons.  For the pros and a starting point, you can start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content).  For the cons, read [this](https://medium.engineering/why-contenteditable-is-terrible-122d8a40e480).

Comment: First of all, i would like to thank you for your answer. My main problem is not how to edit the elements in html. (i have found the first link page that you have send me) but how i could create the same layout of mpdf function in a html page, in order to use the contenteditable. I have used mpdf and i have created successfully the pdf (exactly with the view that i want) but when i choose "not" output in pdf in order to edit the element output then the html view is totally different.

Comment: Your HTML page must mimic printed paper given the limitations of screen resolution.  An A4 page is 8.27 inches wide (I'm in the U.S.).  At 150dpi that's 1240.5 pixels wide.  Use Javascript to set the inner width of your browser window to 1240 pixels (if your monitor doesn't support this, reduce DPI).  At this point your HTML should look similar to the mPDF output.  If it doesn't, you should re-post your question with specific code for a limited number of HTML objects so we can run some tests.